# COM InternetExplorer.Application Behavior

Tags: powershell, com, internet-explorer-11

Been wrestling with parsing the HP Warranty website since the web service method seems to be constantly changing.

Problem I am having is I have tried to use the internet explorer com and its acting different depending on a version difference somewhere either PS or IE of which I am not certain how to tell.

Here is my core portion of code that I am testing with. You would need to find an HP Serial Number to test with.

```
$SerialNumber = ""
$link = "http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/wc/public/find?rows%5B0%5D.item.serialNumber=" + $SerialNumber + "&rows%5B0%5D.item.countryCode=US&submitButton=Submit"
            Write-Verbose "Calling: $link" 

            $request = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
            $request.UseDefaultCredentials = "True"
            $request.Proxy = [System.Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()
            $results = $request.downloadstring($link)

            if($results -match "Base Warranty") {

                Write-Verbose "Results contain Warranty Data"

                $results | Out-File "C:\Temp\Warranty.html" -Encoding ascii

                $oIE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
                $oIE.Navigate("C:\Temp\Warranty.html")
                $ohtmldoc = $oIE.Document
                $rows = $ohtmldoc.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("hpui-normal-row")

                $data = $rows[0].ChildNodes | ? {$_.TagName -eq "td"}
                $ExpireDate = Date($data[4].InnerText)

            } else {
                Write-Verbose "Results do not contain Warranty Data"
                $ExpireDate = ""
                }
```

Works fine on my win 10 machine with IE11 v11.212.10586.0; PSVersion 5.0

Failing  win 2008 R2 Term servers with IE11 v11.0.9600.17873CO in two different fashions; PSVersion 4.0

It appears that the DOM is not populating the `ChildNodes` property from the `$rows[0]` variable after it parses the ClassName.

Aside from the above being my main issue,
Another 2008 R2 Term server as soon as I invoke the `$oIE.Navigate` Method it opens an instance of an IE window for the link being called then the rest of the commands fail which I haven't seen happen yet on my other two environments.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated as I don't often use the InternetExplorer.Application COM. I really just need to be able to parse this HTML content to get the table data effectively. I had tried ditching the COM and ingesting the HTML contents as XML but HP has several malformed lines on the page this warranty result kicks back.

Comment: In general, it's possible to automate IE regardless of whether the window is visible or hidden, so just having the window show up should not cause everything to fail. I wonder if that's because the HP site is somewhere in the Trusted Sites/Intranet/Custom lists on that terminal server, and that's triggering a new IE process to launch so it can load the site in a different security context, and then the commands fail because it's not the same process connected to your COM automation anymore. Have a look if you can find *.hp.com in the IE settings on that server, different to the others.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I actually had a similar thought since that server does sit under a different OU with different GPO's applying. I figured I would be able to track that one issue down but didn't want to waste time on it if the `ChildNode` problem trumped it all together. Thanks for confirming my thoughts on that one!